# Formula for making maximum number of rational numbers with two integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Imagine we have a formula that is supposed to create a rational number out of two given numbers:

```
uint8_t x;
 
uint8_t y;
```

Here `x` and `y` are two 8-bit numbers that are limited between `0` to `255`.

If I create a formula such as `x/(y+1)` to create rational numbers out of them, there are many repetitive rational numbers such as `10/5` and `6/3` that are waste. They are just equal to `2/1` (`x=2, y=0`). I am not interested in them. On the other hand, I am not interested in making a lookup table either. I need a function that produces such rational numbers in a reasonable size (mathematicians can argue what does reasonable mean).

I am also interested in the formula results just in the range of `(0,2]`.

Dose discrete math have any solution for creating the formula to give the maximum number of unique rational numbers within range of `(0,2]` out of two 8-bit numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $2\cdot\frac{256x+y+1}{256^2}$?

Comment: How would this generate $5/3$ for example?

Comment: It wouldn't. OP just asked for the maximum number of unique outputs, which this delivers. No matter what formula you use you can only get $256^2$ possible results - you're going to miss some rationals.

Comment: If the OP feels that numbers with small denominators should be included, they can look into generating a Farey sequence, but that really wouldn't be a "formula in x and y" like they requested.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.